# Does RB URF02 ultra sonic sensor give false readings?

Tags: sensor, measuring

There's only 1 raspberry pi shop in my country and he offers only two ultra sonic sensors [HC - SR04](http://www.ekt2.com/products/productdetails?ProductId=2ec67a91-978e-4a2f-8524-e672539d9644) and [RB URF02](http://www.ekt2.com/products/productdetails?ProductId=7831f07a-2266-4745-bbed-8c0705082df2) there's a pdf on the pages I linked to for more information. RB URF02 is so much more expensive.

I have tried HC - SR04, and it gives false distances sometimes, precision is important in my project. I have never tried RB URF02 but it looks the same to me, only much more expensive. Money is no problem if the sensor is that good. Is it? Cause I have to buy 4 of them

Have anyone tried RB URF02? Is it reliable? Does it give wrong readings? Is it so much better than the cheaper one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is with your HC-SR04 sensor?  Most of the posted code I've seen contains errors.

The only oddity I've noticed with the HC-SR04 is that sometimes the echo line stays high when no echo is detected.  It really ought to go low after a timeout period (which the specs say it should).

I tried a series of experiments documented at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=563957#p563957

I tend to use code similar to the following to read the sensor.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# HC_SR04.py
# 2015-08-06
# Public Domain

import time

import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

class sensor:

   def __init__(self, pi, trigger, echo):

      self._pi    = pi
      self._trig = trigger
      self._echo = echo

      self._tick = None
      self._distance = 0.0
      self._new = False

      pi.set_mode(self._trig, pigpio.OUTPUT)
      pi.set_mode(self._echo, pigpio.INPUT)

      self._cb = pi.callback(self._echo, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, self._cbf)

   def _cbf(self, gpio, level, tick):

      if level == 1:
         self._tick = tick
      else:
         if self._tick is not None:
            ping = pigpio.tickDiff(self._tick, tick)
            self._distance = ping * 17015.0 / 1000000.0
            self._new = True

   def trigger(self):

      self._tick = None
      self._pi.gpio_trigger(self._trig, 10)

   def get_centimetres(self):

      new = self._new
      self._new = False
      return self._distance, new

   def cancel(self):

      self._cb.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   import time
   import pigpio
   import HC_SR04

   pi = pigpio.pi()


   sonar = HC_SR04.sensor(pi, trigger=20, echo=21)

   end = time.time() + 1000.0

   r = 1
   while time.time() < end:

      sonar.trigger()
      time.sleep(0.1)
      cms, new = sonar.get_centimetres()
      print("{} {:.1f} {}".format(r, cms, new))
      r += 1

   sonar.cancel()

   pi.stop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure but since one sensor is extremely cheap and the other is extremely expensive, I took a guess, since you get what you pay for.

Comment: thanks for your code, I'll try it tomorrow! really grateful

Comment: @Lynob The sensors look pretty much the same to me.  The RB URF02 has a range of 5 metres rather than 4 which might explain the difference in price.  I don't believe paying more is any guarantee of quality or correctness.  I have countless counter examples from my own experience.